# Ripple gives a 503 error on an XMLRPC call to an internal server

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ripple

I am creating a phonegap app using JqueryMobile and Cordova.
When I deploy the app to an android device all is running great.

But for faster and easier testing I want to use Ripple.

When I test in ripple my application is looking ok, and phonegap calls like vibrate are working.

My app however executes XMLRPC calls to an internal server. This gives 503 errors when using Ripple.
If I don't use Ripple these calls executes no problem in the browser, but than (logically) the phonegap stuff isn't working.

This is the error I am seeing in the Chrome developer console :  POST https://rippleapi.herokuapp.com/xhr_proxy?tinyhippos_apikey=ABC&tinyhippos_rurl=http%3A//openerp-test.fks.be%3A8089/xmlrpc/common 503 (Service Unavailable)

Note that I am running Chrome with --disable-web-security to avoid same origin problems.

Anyone ever had something like this, or knows how to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Go to 'settings' in right-top of the Ripple emulator. Go to 'Cross Domain Proxy' and select 'disabled'.